# How to configure Docker Compose Containers with network_mode and depends_on

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I am trying to configure a `docker-compose` setup so that I can access the `MySQL` container (and probably `redis` and others) from `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` from my main `app` container. This is to mimic the setup at my hosting where the Database is a separate server but still accessible by `localhost`.

I tried using `network_mode: services:app` in `mysql` and `phpmyadmin` services to get what I wanted but it conflicts with `depends_on` because of **Circular Dependency**. I also need the dependencies to start up with the `app` container.

Is there a way to configure this from `docker-compose` or do I set up forwarding on the `app`'s `Dockerfile`?

My `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
    app:
      container_name: app
      build: .
      volumes:
        - .:/var/project
      working_dir: /var/project
      ports:
        - "8080:80"
      depends_on:
        - mysql
        - phpmyadmin

    composer:
      restart: 'no'
      image: composer:latest
      command: install --ignore-platform-reqs
      volumes:
        - .:/var/project
      working_dir: /var/project

    node:
      restart: 'no'
      image: node:8
      command: npm install
      volumes:
        - .:/var/project
      working_dir: /var/project

    mysql:
      image: mysql:5.7
      container_name: mysql
      network_mode: services:app
      environment:
          MYSQL_DATABASE: app_db
          MYSQL_USER: app
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: app
          MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: "true"

    phpmyadmin:
      image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
      container_name: phpmyadmin
      network_mode: services:app
      restart: always
      environment:
        PMA_HOST: mysql
        PMA_PORT: 3306
        PMA_USER: app
        PMA_PASSWORD: app
```

Comment: In general, we could join multiple container into one specific network, is that enough for you?

Comment: @Light.G , The scenario I am trying to achieve is to have a main container (`app`) with some ports on it mapped to ports on other containers. Like MySQL on port 3306 so that I can access it via `127.0.0.1:3306` instead of `mysql:3306` from the main container. Similarly, Redis will be accessible from `127.0.0.1:6379` though it will be a separate container. Is this doable in the `docker-compose.yml` or do I have to explicitly set up some sort of forwarding in the main container `Dockerfile`.

Comment: As I aware and you requirement, you may deploy MySQL first, then phpmyadmin, and app at last. Let phpmyadmin and app take the network service:mysql. And at the same time, let app depends on mysql and phpmyadmin. This would work. Guess you may need a try. If it works, please let me and others know.